# Display images from WordPress post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, loops, wordpress-theming

I have a loop - It is pulling all the posts from category id # 4. I want to upload the image but NOT insert it when i'm writing my post. How can i make it so that i can pull the images uploaded that i uploaded for each post since its in the loop?

```
<?php query_posts('cat=4'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<h3><?php the_content(); ?></h3>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this link and the code was the answer:

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-get-all-post-attachments-in-wordpress-except-for-featured-image/